# load function after page switch on querymobile ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jquerymobile ajax based web app. not using ajax is no option. 
On one page a new script is inserted by `<script url="../script.js"></script>`

Now i would like to load that script, after the page is loaded by ajax. Unfortunately it does not happen. I tried for example:

```
 $(document).live( 'pageinit',function(event)
     CODE HERE
{});
```

But it does not work. As well as

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function()
```

Any ideas how i can manage to load the function after the page is loaded by ajax??

Comment: Place script inside page div.

Comment: if i do so the following errors appear: http://cl.ly/image/1t11320Z1M23

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution with help of "OMAR". I put the function inside the page div. But the link is not working, so i put the code itself into the top of the div. now it is working. not the best solution, but it is working.